# How to convert A/m to dBμA/m?

Tags: electromagnetic, field-strength, math-notation

Lets say I have -2 dBμA/m as a limit.

How do I convert the magnetic field strength in A/m to dBμA/m? Is it as follows?

$$20\cdot \log(\frac{ |H| }{10^{-6}})$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the units of H are A/m, then dividing by 10^-6 will convert the amperes into microamperes.  Taking the logarithm to base 10 of the result and multiplying by 20 will indeed convert the original value in A/m to dB//uA/m. Your formula is correct.